# Regular expression to search exact string within parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string matching problem.

```
System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(pagePath);
string content = objReader.ReadToEnd();
objReader.Close();

string stringToSearch = "PO";  
string PatternToMatch = @"(" + stringToSearch + ")";
ReplaceText = "<a href ='#'>" + stringToSearch + "</a>";

content = Regex.Replace(content, PatternToMatch, ReplaceText);

// writing the content to the same file
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pagePath);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Close();
```

here, firstly i am reading whole content of page and storing it in a variable content.
   then, there is a string PatternToMatch which i am searching for in the whole page.

If there is a string matching, then replace those words within parenthesis with the provided one.

In case there is a string matching with parenthesis around then it works fine. but at some places, it is
   replacing the words without parenthesis. 
   So, how should i restrict it.

Suppose, there is a string like this --

```
 BANGLORE POP is backed up with DELHI POP as backup gateway.
```

here, it is replacing PO with anchor tag but there is no '(' and ')' so why it fails here.

Please suggest the regex to match exact words within parenthesis.

Comment: A parenthesis is a special character in regex language.  A real parenthesis you need to put a backslash before the parenthesis "\(" and "\)".

Comment: Are you trying to only match a quantity in parentheses, or both with and without parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `(` and `)`, otherwise [capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/eTlbz4/2) will be created, instead of [match](https://regex101.com/r/eTlbz4/3).

```
string PatternToMatch = @"\(" + stringToSearch + @"\)";
```

Comment: @neo examples are already provided, click on links in answer.

Comment: please help me can u tell me pattern for word with comma and dot just after the word ends. it should match only word with comma and word with dot and do replace there

Comment: tell me something like this, i was trying this --   `string PatternToMatch = " " + stringToSearch + @"\,";`

Comment: try `stringToSearch + @"\,\."`, you have to escape `.` because its special character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151466/discussion-between-neo-and-tchelidze).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# regexes per se. PCRE or Posix regexes use `(` ... `)` to mark matching-groups, i.e., parts of the target that will be referred to later as "$1" or "\1", particularly when doing a match and substitution.
To treat "(" itself as a non-metachar, it needs to be escaped; in most languages, that would be using "\(". I also don't know about \-escaping in C# strings, but you probably need to double up the backslash so it looks like `"\\\\(" + stringToSearch + "\\\\)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without Regex replacing:

```
content.Replace(PatternToMatch, ReplaceText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply search for a symbol in regular expression it should be preceded by **\** so if you want to search **(** then it should be **\(**.

```
string ReplaceText = "BANGLORE (PO)P is backed up with DELHI POP as backup gateway.";
string stringToSearch = "PO";
string PatternToMatch = @"\(" + stringToSearch + @"\)";
string ReplaceText = "<a href ='#'>" + stringToSearch + "</a>";

content = Regex.Replace(content, PatternToMatch, ReplaceText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis have a special meaning for a regexp.

Note that this is a problem also for other characters... and for example if you need to search for the string `a*b+c` you will need to "escape" also the asterisk and plus sign as they've a special meaning too.

If you don't need the power of a regular expression then the best solution is not using a regular expression but just plain text replacing. In C# apparently is:

```
content = content.replace(stringToSearch,
                          "<a href ='#'>" + stringToSearch + "</a>");
```